# Confused about java 9 ServiceLoader::load method and the way how to provide a service impl

Tags: java, java-9

In this java document:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html
Deploying service providers as modules chapter,it says:

> com.example.impl.ExtendedCodecsFactory is a public class that does not implement CodecFactory, but it declares a public static no-args method named "provider" with a return type of CodecFactory.

But the fact is I can't use `provides...with` to provide a service implementation and it will throw a compile error and runtime error without implement the service.

Is that possible I provide a public static provider method and I can provide a service implementation without define `provides...with` in module-info file?
Confused,hope someone can help.

Comment: The static provider method is only support by service providers that are deployed as modules. Are you asking if you have have a static provider method when deploy on the class path (with a service configuration file in META-INF/services)?

Comment: Thanks for you comment.I mean I don't understand 'com.example.impl.ExtendedCodecsFactory is a public class that does not implement CodecFactory, but it declares a public static no-args method named "provider" with a return type of CodecFactory.' said in the docs,it will throw a compile error and runtime error in fact if you do not implement the interface and use `provides...with`

Comment: When you have a compiler error, you should include the code necessary to reproduce the error in your question. Also, posting the exact error message might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the class with the provider method ends up in a module, this works fine. I just created [a small demo project](https://github.com/CodeFX-org/demo-jpms-hello-services) showing that:

```
// MODULE com.example.codec.api

public interface CodecFactory { }

module com.example.codec.api {
    exports com.example.codec;
    uses com.example.codec.CodecFactory;
}


// MODULE com.example.codec.impl

public class ExtendedCodecsFactory {

    public static CodecFactory provider() {
        return new CodecFactory() { };
    }

}

module com.example.codec.impl {
    requires com.example.codec.api;
    provides com.example.codec.CodecFactory
        with com.example.impl.ExtendedCodecsFactory;
}
```

To compile:

```
javac
    -d classes/com.example.codec.api
    src/com.example.codec.api/module-info.java
    src/com.example.codec.api/com/example/codec/CodecFactory.java
javac
    -p classes/com.example.codec.api
    -d classes/com.example.codec.impl
    src/com.example.codec.impl/module-info.java
    src/com.example.codec.impl/com/example/impl/ExtendedCodecsFactory.java
```

If you're trying to create a service provider that does not live in a module, the provider methods won't work. Unfortunately, [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) is not terribly clear in this regard. The section *Deploying service providers on the class path* mentions neither provider constructors nor provider methods, in fact it doesn't even mention inheritance.

The closest you get is in the section above that:

> #### Deploying service providers as modules
>
> [...]
>
> A service provider that is deployed as an automatic module on the application module path must have a provider constructor. There is no support for a provider method in this case.

That covers putting plain JARs without module descriptor onto the module path.

Comment: Please clarify your question to demonstrate what went wrong. Otherwise it won't help other users.

Comment: In fact I can define the provider without implement the interface and provide a static `provider` method like above.But if the interface declares normal methods,I still need to override all the non-static methods in `provider` method.

Comment: in the sample code above (second comment)  the module name should be     // MODULE  com.example.codec.impl