# Using ServiceLoader to implement a JRE service, but without modules

Tags: java

We have a very large project under Java 8.  I temporarily need to use a feature<sup>1</sup> introduced in Java 9 in order to debug a problem, so my plan was to build and run with mostly-current tools (probably 11.0.1), add minimal code to call the feature, and then simply not merge any of the debugging changes to the trunk.

The challenge is that I don't want to have to slog through constructing a `module-info.java` merely for this.  (The existing non-module code actually builds and runs with no problems under Java SE 11, it's just that the production user environment is constrained to Java 8.  Thus, we've made almost no effort to try and modularize this project.)

Why modules might matter:  the feature I need to use is `System.LoggerFinder`, which is found via `ServiceLoader`.  The hip new way of using `ServiceLoader` is via module declarations, and that's what the current service loader documentation spends most time describing.  The old way of putting text files under `META-INF/services/` still works, and we're already successfully using such services and provider classes, but the current setup isn't working with `LoggerFinder`.

The temporary class we're trying to load

```java
package com.example.for.stackoverflow;

public class LoggerFinder extends System.LoggerFinder
{
    public LoggerFinder()
    {
        System.err.println("behold, a LoggerFinder");
    }


    @Override
    public System.Logger getLogger (String name, Module module)
    {
        org.slf4j.Logger real = ...existing function to fetch logging facade...
        return new SystemLoggerWrapper (name, real);
    }
}

class SystemLoggerWrapper implements System.Logger { ... }
```

This kind of wrapper implementation is pretty straightforward, and has been published elsewhere.<sup>2</sup>  However, the published examples all use 
`module-info.java` to get `ServiceLoader` to DTRT.

This project's build system is done with Ant, so we've added lines under the `<jar>` task:

```
<service type="java.lang.System.LoggerFinder">
  <provider classname="com.example.for.stackoverflow.LoggerFinder"/>
</service>
```

This works, in that the final JAR contains a `META-INF/services/java.lang.System.LoggerFinder` text file containing the proper classname.

However, at runtime, the provided `LoggerFinder` isn't used.  Looking through the output of `-verbose:class` it's clear that the defaults are all still in play.  There are no exceptions thrown from `ServiceLoader` itself.  The runtime classpath is already picking up the JAR where the `LoggerFinder` implementation lives (it's not the only service, and the other `ServiceLoader`-esque providers *are* being found).

A very few existing questions on SO touch on the topic,
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48090929)
and
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49353106),
but they also take the modular route.

Is there some way of getting visibility into what `ServiceLoader` is doing?
Is this just an exercise in futility without a `modules-info.java`?

---

<sup>1</sup>  I'm trying to activate debug messages from the `sun.util.logging.PlatformLogger` system, which (at least as of Java 9) will work through `System.Logger`, and become activated if -- according to its own documentation -- a `System.LoggerFinder` can be found by ServiceLoader.  All of this juggling is aimed towards that PlatformLogger goal.

<sup>2</sup>  for example, https://www.baeldung.com/java-9-logging-api under section three

Comment: The documentation of [`LoggerFinder`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.LoggerFinder.html) says it looks for implementations visible to the [system class loader](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getSystemClassLoader()); if none are found, it falls back to the default. Is your provider visible to the system class loader?

Comment: What are you *really* trying to do? It seems you're trying to redirect calls to `java.util.logging` to SLF4J, so its connected logging library (e.g. Logback) can be used. That is exactly what the [jul-to-slf4j bridge](https://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html#jul-to-slf4j) is for, so why are you trying to re-invent the wheel?

Comment: @Andreas We already use the jul-to-slf4j bridge with no problems, but JUL isn't picking up anything from the PlatformLogger.  From seeing which classes are being loaded (e.g., the "ThisOnlyGetsUsedAsFallback.class" sort of names), it's clear that none of the activation conditions are being met by simply relying on JUL and nothing else.  Thus the attempt at providing a `LoggerFinder`.

Comment: @Slaw I can only say this for a fact:  "The provider (and everything else in the `com.example....` packages) is found in locations specified with `-cp` at launch."  My understanding is that `-cp` controls, or at least informs, the system class loader.  Does the sentence in quotation marks properly answer the question you asked?  Because if `-cp` doesn't do the system class loader in 9+ then we're just SOL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way `ServiceLoader` loads classes on the classpath hasn't changed<sup>1</sup>. It still locates providers by searching for appropriate provider-configuration files under `META-INF/services`.

The documentation of [`LoggerFinder`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.LoggerFinder.html) says it searches for providers visible to the [system class loader](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getSystemClassLoader()). As you mention in a comment the provider is included via `-cp` this should not be an issue.

The provider-configuration file's name must be the *fully qualified binary name* of the SPI. From the [`ServiceLoader`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) documentation:

> #### *Deploying service providers on the class path*
>
> A service provider that is packaged as a JAR file for the class path is identified by placing a *provider-configuration file* in the resource directory `META-INF/services`. The name of the provider-configuration file is the fully qualified binary name of the service. The provider-configuration file contains a list of fully qualified binary names of service providers, one per line.

The binary name of `LoggerFinder`, as returned by [`Class.getName`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getName()), is `java.lang.System$LoggerFinder`. Based on that, the provider-configuration file's name should be:

```
META-INF/services/java.lang.System$LoggerFinder
```

I'm not at all familiar with Ant, but I'd guess you should change the value of `type` to use the fully qualified binary name.

```xml
<service type="java.lang.System$LoggerFinder">
  <provider classname="com.example.for.stackoverflow.LoggerFinder"/>
</service>
```

*Note: When testing this on my own, I initially couldn't get the system to use my `LoggerFinder` implementation either. When I changed the provider-configuration file name to `java.lang.System$LoggerFinder` (once finally reading the docs) then it worked as expected. Unfortunately, I don't have Ant available to test a solution with the `<jar>` task.*

---

<sup>1. Unless you use `ServiceLoader.load(ModuleLayer,Class)` as it will ignore the unnamed modules (i.e. classpath).</sup>

Comment: I can't believe I forgot to use `$` instead.  God, what a brainfart.  I'm going to go home and drink Scotch until I forget about this mistake.... but first I'll fix the Ant file.  :-)   Thank you very much!